# Java fx StyleClassedTextArea text font and color

Tags: java, javafx, frontend

I'm coding an IDE by using JavaFx without using CSS files.
I've created a StyleClassedTextArea Object and  I want to set it a background color, a font family and a text color.

Here is what I've done :

```
textArea = new StyleClassedTextArea();
textArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + toRGBCode(Color.rgb(0, 32, 40)));
textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'OCR A Extended';");
textArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(LineNumberFactory.get(textArea));
```

The problem is that the background color is correctly changed but when I add the line for the font family, the background become white.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Every setStyle statement will overwrite the previous one . You need to set style in a css file

Comment: If you don't want to use a CSS file as suggested by Giovanni, then you need to put all the styles in a single `String` and then pass that string to `setStyle` (or, in newer versions of JavaFX, passed to `getStylesheets().add(...)` with a `data:` url). You can do this inline, splitting up the lines and concatenating the strings, or using a multi-line string (i.e., a string surrounded by `"""`).